# easiest proof of the Prime Number Theorem to study and teach?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I know there are several variants of proofs for the Prime Number Theorem.

Which one is the easiest one to study and then re-teach?

By easiest, I mean those that assume minimal knowledge beyond secondary school mathematics.

For example, most school leavers having done maths will have calculus, and could stretch to understand concepts like asymptotic equivalence and integration in the complex plane, but won't have concepts like group theory.

Comment: "Minimal knowledge beyond secondary school mathematics" will most likely not be the simplest proof by far. Learning concepts that are missing and then checking a simpler proof with stronger requirements might be overall easier.

Comment: I agree wiith gnasher729.

Comment: @gnasher729 - I understand your point. If you have suggestions for such a simple proof I would appreciate it. I am looking at an "analytic" proof and an 'elementary" proof and the analytic one s of course simpler as the concepts are more powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might check out

***D. Zagier, Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem***,

which appears in

***The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 104, No. 8 (Oct., 1997), pp. 705-708***

and is available online at

***http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975232***.

This is the easiest proof of which I am aware, but its challenging nevertheless.  But an undergrad with a solid background in analysis should be able to hack it.